Is there an image upload limit in ChatGPT Plus?
I'm currently using the free version of ChatGPT, and I can upload only 3 images per session. After that, I have to wait for 4 hours before the next session. I was considering upgrading to ChatGPT Plus for $20 per month, but I am unsure if there are any limits on the number of images I can upload with the premium version.
Does ChatGPT Plus also have an image upload limit? If so, how many images can I upload?
Thanks!

Yes, ChatGPT Plus also has an image upload limit. You can typically upload up to 10 images per session or conversation.
